# Facebook app description and Like button

Tags: facebook, facebook-iframe

I added social plugin to my app(IFRAME)- "Like button". After adding
a plugin, I decided to change page description. 
Everything seems to be ok, except description remains old 
in "Like" plugin window...

So how to make it fresh?

Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run it through the [URL Linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/).